# Create an Array of void*, Each Pointing to 2d int Matrix?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, matrix

I want to create a dynamic array of `void*`s, each `void*` will point to 2d `int` matrix.

All of the matrices have the same number of rows and columns.

How to do this in C?

What do I do after I initialize: `void **myArray = NULL;`

More specifically, I want to create a function, that takes 2 parameters:

```
int foo( void* matrix, void** ptrArray)
```

Where `matrix` points to 2d `int` matrix, `ptrArray` points to an array of `void*`s, and `foo` returns the size of `ptrArray`.

I want, `foo` to get the 2d `int` matrix from `matrix` and make some manipulations on it, like switch some numbers in it. For every change that I make, I want to allocate a new matrix, and save a pointer to it in `ptrArray`.

Comment: It would actually be a `void*` that you will `malloc`. Because your matrix are of fixed length you can statically declare them as `int matrix[LENGTH][LENGTH]`.
With this information and a bit of research effort you should succeed.

Comment: @Coconop first tnx a lot. second, i don't understand what to write inside the malloc..malloc(1*sizof(void *)?

Comment: @user3552460 The only way that `foo` makes sense is if the argument to `ptrArray` is not pointing to anything currently. Otherwise you'll also need to pass a size.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to dynamically allocate each matrix.

For purposes of example I'm going to assume that you are creating your "2d `int` matrix" as a linear, 16 `int` array.

```
#define MATRIX_SIZE 16

int foo(void* matrix, void** ptrArray){
    assert(ptrArray == NULL);

    int result = 0;
    int* first = malloc(MATRIX_SIZE * sizeof(int));

    //do stuff to matrix
    for(int i = 0; i < MATRIX_SIZE; ++i){
        first[i] = matrix[i];
    }
    ptrArray = malloc((++result) * sizeof(void*));
    ptrArray[0] = (void*)first;

    int* second = malloc(MATRIX_SIZE * sizeof(int));

    //do stuff to matrix
    for(int i = 0; i < MATRIX_SIZE; ++i){
        second[i] = matrix[i];
    }
    ptrArray = realloc((++result) * sizeof(void*));
    ptrArray[1] = (void*)second;
    .
    .
    .
    return result;
}
```

Comment: tnx jonathan, but the problem is that i don't know how much matrices i want to add. i know that there are "some" matrices and  with a loop, insert each matrix to the array

Comment: @user3552460 For starters I'd edit your question. Specifically, how is your loop controlled? Is it like this: `for(int i = 0; i < foo; i++)` If so then you should initialize `void** myArray = calloc(foo, sizeof(void*));`

Comment: jonathan, i can't do this :#define MATRIX_SIZE 16
i need to get the matrix from c, and figure what is the size of the matrix it points to

Comment: @user3552460 Then it sounds like you'll have to pass in the matrix size as a parameter to `foo` and use that to allocate your `first`, `second`, ... as well.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you allocate your void **twodarray somewhere else and you put NULL in the last+1 element of this array.

I think you want to do something like this;

```
  int function(void **twodarray,void **ptrarray)
  {
  int i=0
  for(i=0;twodarray[i]!=NULL;i++)/*repeat till twodarray points to NULL*/
  {
      perform some operation on twodarray[i];
      ptrarray[i]=twodarray[i];
  }
  return i+1;/*return length of ptrarray */
  }
```

This way you can tell the no of matrices there are.
But you will have to work out the allocation of void **twodarray by the methods explained in other replies.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27271985/void-pointers-to-2d-int-array rahul i edited the question here can you help me?